# How to auto-update a "Status Reason" field of a CRM entity, based on specific condition?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-2016

Following is the exact scenario in my CRM implementation:

There are two entities:

1. Customer >> Customer Name, Auto-update customer orders?
2. Order >> Order Date, Order Amount

Order entity has standard status and status reason fields, where status reason has options such as -> "Added to cart", "Ordered", "Reminder to Buy", "Delivered"

The ultimate goal is to set status reason of Order entity to "Reminder to Buy", if the current status reason is "Ordered", and current date is "Order Date + 12 days" for all customers having "Auto-update customer records?"

Can anyone please suggest what should be the best approach to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Order date is set when the status changes to Ordered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the better option here is an **async workflow**.

Create a workflow on the Order entity and fire it when the status changes (Update of Status Reason).

After fired, ask if the field "Auto-update" in the Customer is true, then add an step with a wait condition **12 days** after Order date. After 12 days if the status is Ordered, change this status to Reminder to Buy.

[Here](http://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/paul-nieuwelaars-blog/2012/11/25/workflow-wait-conditions-best-practices-dynamics-crm-2011) is an example of wait conditions.